# How to select columns from preloaded data and group in Ecto?

Tags: mysql, database, join, elixir, ecto

I have 3 tables: `sales`, `products`, and `sales_products`. Sales contains information about sales made as the name implies, products contains information about various products, and sales_products is an intermediary table with a `sale_id` + `product_id` composite key, and a quantity field.

My current Ecto query looks like this:

```
    query =
      from s in Sale,
      inner_join: sp in SaleProduct,
      on: sp.sale_id == s.id,
      inner_join: p in Product,
      on: p.id == sp.product_id,
      group_by: s.id,
      order_by: [asc: :date],
      preload: [:sale_products]
```

This works in that I get a result similar to:

```
[%Sale{
    [...],
    sale_id: ID,
    sale_products: [
      %SaleProduct { product: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :product is not loaded>, sale_id: ID, product_id: PID }
    ],
    [...]
}]
```

Firstly, how do I preload 'product' for SaleProduct when it is inside its own preloaded struct?

And secondly, and the main question, how do I select only specific columns from `sale_products`? I am trying to return this as a `json` Object, however I get a Poison error as it does not know how to encode some fields, and I just want to select the fields I need from the SaleProduct struct to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

To preload product for SaleProduct, you just nest the preload:

```
preload: [..., saleproducts: [:product], ...]
```

And to solve the overarching question, you actually don't use preload at all, but rather `fragment`:

```
select: %{products: fragment("JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('product_id', ?, 'quantity', ?))", sp.product_id, sp.quantity)}
```